Ag Grid Column Style
I am using AG Grid in one of my project. I want to style the entire column in Ag grid based on one cell value. Currently I am using
cellStyle:params =>{
    if (params.value == "STRING1"){return {backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'}}
}

which is giving result as first Image.First Image
but I am excepting output like the second Image Second Image
I am excepting output like the second Image Second Image

You are looking for getRowStyle which styles the entire row, based on a condition
<ag-grid-angular [getRowStyle]="getStyles"></ag-grid-angular>

in the TS file
...
getStyles(params: any) {
  if (params?.node?.data?.['<<give the property name that you need to check here!>>'] === "STRING1") {
     return {backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'}
  }
  return {};
};
...

Aggrid Docs Reference
